# Unique field validation issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-6

I'm trying to validate a unique entry in my laravel app

following is my validation array,

```
$website = $websiteModel->find($id);

        $this->validate($request, [
            'subDomainName' => ['required','regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/'],
            'subDomainSuffix' => ['required'], 
            'packageType' => ['required'],
            'themeid' => ['required'],
            'lang' => ['required'],
            'user' => ['required'],
            'domain' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'min:2',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique('apps')->ignore($website)
            ],
        ], $request->all());
```

My validation working properly BUT,

When i tried to enter a duplicate value for my domain field, It get validated properly but not showing the error message, saying sorry the name is already exists...

```
<input type="text" id="domain" class="form-control" name="domain" >
{!! $errors->first('domain', '<span class="help-block" role="alert">:message</span>') !!}
```

Here in this span it shows nothing but in the common error message area it shows sorry the form cannot be updated... So how can I validate the field properly and display the relevant error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do something like this:

On insert request use

```
'domain' => [
   ...
   'unique:websites,domain'
]
```

On update request use

```
'domain' => [
   ...
   "unique:websites,domain,{$this->website->id}"
]
```

Or

```
'domain' => [
   ...
   Rule::unique('websites', 'domain')->ignore($this->website)
]
```

Comment: made a small change to your answer, in the update line, your code gave me an error so I changed it to Rule::unique('apps', 'domain')->ignore($website), and that worked for me. :). Thanks for the guide.

Answer (score 0):

You passed $request->all() as validation messages. 
Please Try:

```
$website = $websiteModel->find($id);

        $request->validate([
            'subDomainName' => ['required','regex:/^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/'],
            'subDomainSuffix' => ['required'], 
            'packageType' => ['required'],
            'themeid' => ['required'],
            'lang' => ['required'],
            'user' => ['required'],
            'domain' => [
                'required',
                'string',
                'min:2',
                'max:255',
                Rule::unique('apps')->ignore($website)
            ],
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

don't you need to pass duplicate column in ignore Rule To instruct the validator to ignore the website domain, except for it self ? for example like

```
Rule::unique('apps')->ignore($website->id)
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this one . it helps to solve your problem

use exception and validator in top of the file

```html
use Exception;
use Validator;
```

```html
$rules = [
                'subDomainName' => 'required|unique:sub_domain_name',
            ];

            $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules, $message);
            if ($validator->fails()) {
                throw new Exception(implode('\n', $validator->errors()->all()));
            }
```

sub_domain_name : this is database column name